# How to render text of QGraphicsSimpleTextItem from right to left in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicstextitem

I've an Object that inherits from QGraphicsRectItem and looks like schematic.

[image]

i want to render the red underlined QGraphicsSimpletextItem inside the rectangle so that it renders from right to left.

Is there any function in Qt that can render QGpahicsSimpleTextItem from right to left given the co-ordinates?